# "libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile" when using tkinter.filedialog

Tags: python-3.x

I get "**libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile**" warnings from my simple python program, however, I think it should be PNG file format related warning, but my program is not containing any PNG related code, just to open an excel file and output the content.

```
Tk().withdraw() 
workbookName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = 'C:/') 
wb = load_workbook(filename=workbookName, read_only=False)

sheetContent = []
for HDnumber in range(1, 30):
    eachsheet = "HD"+str(HDnumber)
    if  eachsheet in wb.sheetnames :
        for row in range(1, wb[eachsheet].max_row+1):
            rowContent = []
            for column in range(1,3):      
                sheet = wb[eachsheet]
                cellValue = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).value
                rowContent.append(cellValue)
            sheetContent.append(rowContent)
print(sheetContent)
```

I think the only cause of the warning is from "filedialog", but don't know why and how to avoid these warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbelievable, I uninstalled the Input Method Editor to solve the problem

Comment: Indeed, I uninstalled QQ IME to solve the problem.I think it's a software conflict. You can have a try.

Comment: Unbelievable, you even know the answer. Yes, you are correct, I uninstalled QQ IME and everything is fine now. Such strange problem...Originally I think nobody will know the reason. Thank you.